# Mantener hover seleccionado y cambiarlo despues

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo un problema tratando de hacer una seccion de mi página web.
Tengo 3 containers (ver foto más abajo), necesito que el primero este con los estilos de hover por default, pero cuando se haga hover en uno de los dos elementos, se quiten los estilos de hover del default y se cambie a los siguientes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, tengo el hover definido en el primer container, pero cuando hago hover en los demás el primero queda seleccionado.

Recapitulando, estoy tratando de que cuando entre a la web el primer container este en hover, y cuando pase el mouse por otro elemento sólo quede ese en hover.

Les comparto el código

HTML:

```
<div class="col-2 first_col">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="upper_icon">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48">
                        <path fill="#202a36" d="M39.8 41.95 26.65 28.8q-1.5 1.3-3.5 2.025-2 .725-4.25.725-5.4 0-9.15-3.75T6 18.75q0-5.3 3.75-9.05 3.75-3.75 9.1-3.75 5.3 0 9.025 3.75 3.725 3.75 3.725 9.05 0 2.15-.7 4.15-.7 2-2.1 3.75L42 39.75Zm-20.95-13.4q4.05 0 6.9-2.875Q28.6 22.8 28.6 18.75t-2.85-6.925Q22.9 8.95 18.85 8.95q-4.1 0-6.975 2.875T9 18.75q0 4.05 2.875 6.925t6.975 2.875Z" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <h4>Investigación</h4>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas quis saepe velit rerum optio quod quia vitae animi porro non!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2">

            <div class="box">
                <div class="upper_icon">

                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48">
                        <path fill="#202a36" d="M13.45 42 13 38.7l6.35-17.5q.55.55 1.225.9t1.425.6l-6.15 16.95Zm21.1 0-2.4-2.35-6.25-16.9q.75-.25 1.45-.6t1.25-.9L35 38.7ZM24 22q-2.5 0-4.25-1.75T18 16q0-2.1 1.225-3.725T22.5 10.2V6h3v4.2q2.05.45 3.275 2.075Q30 13.9 30 16q0 2.5-1.75 4.25T24 22Zm0-3q1.25 0 2.125-.875T27 16q0-1.25-.875-2.125T24 13q-1.25 0-2.125.875T21 16q0 1.25.875 2.125T24 19Z" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <h4>Diseño</h4>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas quis saepe velit rerum optio quod quia vitae animi porro non!</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="upper_icon">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="48" width="48">
                        <path fill="#202a36" d="m16 35.9-12-12 12.1-12.1 2.15 2.15L8.3 23.9l9.85 9.85Zm15.9.1-2.15-2.15 9.95-9.95-9.85-9.85L32 11.9l12 12Z" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <h4>Desarrollo</h4>
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas quis saepe velit rerum optio quod quia vitae animi porro non!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-2 {
        margin: 50px;
        border-radius: 15px;

        .box {
            background: #fff;
            display: flex;
            padding: 30px;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            border-radius: 100px;

            .upper_icon {
                background-color: $lightBlue;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding: 5px;
                width: fit-content;
                height: fit-content;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            h4 {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
        }
    }

    .first_col {
        box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
    }

    .col-2:hover {
        box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
        background-color: transparent;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }
```

Comment: Utilizas Javascript? porque quizas lo necesites para hacer lo que queres.

Comment: Con javascript podrías hacerlo.

Comment: estoy probando con .hover en js! comento cualquier progreso.

Comment: pude lograr hacer el efecto hover con jquery, pero no puedo lograr el objetivo principal de quitar el hover del primer elemento cuando hago hover en otro, cualquier ayuda acerca de como puedo lograrlo con js es bienvenida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero el col-2:hover lo elimino del CSS y me limito a agregar la clase first_col o quitarla dependiendo de lo que necesite (por cierto esos nombres no son realmente apropiados, lo mejor es que un nombre describa lo mejor posible lo que hace esa variable/selector/nodo etc):

```
let cards = document.getElementsByClassName("col-2"); // elijo todos los divs
let previous = cards[0]; // variable que contiene el div que por defecto esta seleccionado

for(const card of cards){ // para cada div
  card.addEventListener("mouseenter",() => { // agrego un evento que de dispara al entrar al div
    if(!card.classList.contains("first_col")) { // si ese div no contiene la clase first_col:
      previous.classList.remove("first_col") // le remueve dicha clase al div seleccionado por defecto
      previous = card; // ahora previous (el div por defecto) es igual al div que disparo este evento
      card.classList.add("first_col") // finalmente le agregamos la clase first_col al div disparador
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo probé y anduvo a la perfección. Gracias por comentar todo el código :)

Comment: con respecto a eso en el if tenes un comentario que dice "si contiene", eso esta mal es "si NO contiene", por eso tengo el ! dentro del if. ahi lo cambio.